# Regex to get percentage not following by specific words

Tags: regex

I want to get percentage in a text that not following 'from' or 'to'
E.g:

- "It decreases 5%" => I want to get 5%
- But "It decreases from 10% to 5%" => I want to get nothing

I've tried some expressions but It does not work. Can you help me?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
/(?!(?<=to|from))(?:\s+)(\d+\%)/
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/NCmjIC/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got 'A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width' error when using Python

Comment: (?!(?<=to))(?!(?<=from))(?:\s+)(\d+\%) works for me, thank you so much!

Comment: It's also can be reduced to (?<!to)(?<!from)(?:\s+)(\d+\%)
https://regex101.com/r/NCmjIC/3